# Calculate Sum of occurrences in Excel

Tags: excel

I currently have the following data set: >>> see first image for dataset and second image for expected outcome

This continues on for about 12 columns with Service_12 and has multiple rows for Company_id about 620,000 rows
I would like a way to find the interaction between services for a company

so i would like to create a table that looks something like this

```
             Service_1                Service_2                Service_3   
Service_1    (Amount of companies     (Amount of companies    (Amount comps
              that used 1               that used                that used  
               Service_1)         service_1 and Service_2)   service1 + sr3)
Service_2     (as above)              (as above)               (as above)
```

I would like this cross service to continue for all 12 services, so for example this is just the sum of the times a company has used both services,

Any ideas?

Thanks

I would like an aoutcome like the folloowing:

my dataset is the following:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Comment: My first thought at seeing this is yuck, maybe use pivot tables.

Comment: used pivot tables but still stuck on what to actually do, lol

Comment: have researched pivot tables, count, countif and sum sumif still got no clue!!!

Comment: Still unclear on your expected outcomes. If company id: 2 used service 2, three times, then would that count as once or three times for that service result (not including any other companies using that service)?

Comment: I've added a new picture to the questionf or you to see an expected outcome

Comment: Try to use this `=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,">0",C2:C5,">0")` this formula should give you an amount of companies that used service 1 (column B) and service 2(column C)

Comment: ^ i just added the number 7 - the actual values dont matter as they change all the time, i just want a way of creating the cross tab

Comment: I added the number 7 myself it corresponds to the company_id that used that service that many times, so company 3 used service_1 7 times!

Comment: forget that data at the beginning the excel cell example with company_id listed is the correct data set - sorry for confusion - any help?

Comment: safe to say that each company will have only used two services and no more than two services?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

`=COUNTIFS(B2:B5,">0",C2:C5,">0")`

this formula should give you how many companies used service 1 (column B) and service 2(column C) or

`=SUMIFS(B2:B5,B2:B5,">0",C2:C5,">0")+SUMIFS(C2:C5,B2:B5,">0",C2:C5,">0")`

if you want to know how many times the station were actually used.

Answer (score -1):

I think a Pivot table would do this.

I would use a dynamic named range to capture your data if you intend to add  companies more often:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-defined-range-in-an-excel-worksheet

If you put "Services" in the rows and columns, and Count(companies) in the values box that should do it!

Comment: did not work at all - pivot table just took the values as counts not the amount per company_id

Comment: Try switching count to sum in the values box? That should count each time a given service is used by each company_id.